# How to configure mac book pro to act as an Access Point (and not a router)?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, airport, internet-sharing

I am connected to internet via ethernet cable on my MBP laptop. I want to have access to internet wirelessly on my iPad as well. How can I config my MBP (OSX 10.6.8) to act as an "Access Point" ?

I already tried the internet sharing via system preferences. 
I could connect to my shared network on my iPad, but the problem is my ISP does now allow network sharing! On my iPad it shows the following error message:

"We have detected that you are using a router or a device that is performing network connection sharing. Sharing a connection with multiple devices is against out term of use."..."You can use a router on our network, however it must be configures to act as an access point."
Then it mentions that I should turn off DHCP in the router settings.

I am in a student residence and do not have access to the ISP's support staff.
The description of the my internet connection contract says that I have right to use two devices manually. There is one ethernet socket in the room.

How can I get internet in my iPad?

Thanks

Comment: is the iPad your's ? This sounds very strange, there schould not be any limiting to Wireless on an iPad. So the way you used was totally fine. The ISP can't even know that you are sharing a network.

Comment: @YoshiBotX,If it wasn't mine, I wasn't using it! Of course iPad is mine! The limitation is NOT with iPad, it is with the ISP. I don't know how, but when I share my internet connection on my laptop, and try to access it on my iPad, the ISP figures it out and prevents it.

Comment: @Buscar웃, Thanks, This link seems like it should work for me as well. I followed the instructions, still the same problem :(  Either it does not connect, or it connects and I get the error message that I am not allowed to use router :(